# How can I find count item from row in R?

Tags: r

[image]

I want to find occurrence of Genre in R. How I can do it? I apply `unique()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `list` column, do

```
lengths(df1$col)
```

and if it is a string column

```
library(stringr)
str_count(df1$col, ",") + 1
```